# Django endpoint to accept xml Feed

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am looking to make an endpoint which  would expect an Outbound message from Say SalesForce. The end point would consume the data (most likey update DB with the data). I was hoping to have some questions answered/clarified.

1) would django rest framework be the way to go?
2) since i dont have much control, I believe the auth-key/token etc would come in as a query string param. Does rest framework allow authentication this way?

Thanks for you time and help.

Regards
Tanmay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most definitely. As long as you know the format of the incoming data from SalesForce, maybe JSON?

1) DRF would most definitely be the way to go. You can easily write an endpoint that accepts a POST request and handles the data preprocessing before saving it to DB

2) Yes, you can do so. You can take a look at writing a Custom Authentication class for that endpoint [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication).

Comment: I believe Salesforce only sends soap messages.